# Is there a way to get at this limit problem algebraically?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{(1-x)}{\cos(x)} $$

Is there a way to get at this probelm algebrically?  L^Hopital's Rule does not work here......sadly.  The answer I got graphing it is that it does not exist.

Comment: Just curious, why do you use boldface for trig functions? There's already the `\sin` command (for example).

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule doesn't work here - the limit on the bottom is neither $0$ nor $\infty$

Comment: @Deusovi I did not know that thanks for the catch.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Thanks for the catch.

Comment: This limit isn't defined, since the function is not defined at any odd multiple of $\pi/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist. If it did, we could take it along any sequence of points which go to infinity. This is typically how people define the limit of a function. It is the limit of a sequence of inputs, and the limit exists if every sequence of inputs converging to some point converges to the same limit.

But we can choose one sequence of points for which cosine is always positive, like say $x_n = 2n\pi$, and $f(x_n) \rightarrow-\infty$ along this sequence, and we can also choose a sequence of points for which cosine is always negative, like $y_n = (2n+1)\pi$, so that $f(y_n) \rightarrow \infty$ along this other sequence.

So we've produced two different sequences with different limits, so the limit doesn't exist.